# Songs with tempo slowing down

Tags: tempo

There are quite few songs that systematically increase tempo (to build tension or increase song energy I suppose). For example Paradise City by Gun's and Roses, Treasure Island by Running Wild or Common People by Pulp.

Are there any relatively popular songs that do the opposite (decrease the tempo) ? And I'm not asking here about simple alternation between slow and fast parts (like Nellie the Elephant by Toy Dolls) - I would like to so hear something that starts fast and then the tempo only goes down.

Comment: what is "relatively popular"? I think this is relatively common in metalcore, but off the top of my head only know of one definite example.

Comment: By relatively popular I mean something that is rather easy to listen to (not some avangarde experimental music that no one listens to). I know that popularity is weak measure of song quality but it tends to filter out most unpleasant stuff.

Comment: Yeah that still doesn't really clarify anything ("easy to listen to" and "unpleasant" are wholly subjective categories that have very little to do with experimentalism -- I don't think many people would call the Minecraft soundtrack difficult or unpleasant, but it's undeniably experimental, actually kinda pushing the boundaries of minimalism), but whatever I'll shoot with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extrem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_L9VrIbFS1g), by We Butter The Bread With Butter, is built primarily around a gradual decrease in tempo. Starting from the end of the intro-verse(?), though it's not immediately obvious that it's happening, the song spends the next two minutes gradually slowing to around ~30 bpm. This is an exaggeration of a relatively common genre convention, demonstrated to a much less absurd extent by the outro breakdown of Escape The Fate's [The Guillotine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jX6Box56CE). Extrem is arguably not a true example in that it does return to its original tempo for the outro; The Guillotine does not return to its original tempo, but the slowdown is very slight once you account for the half-time feel.

[We Are Young](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv6dMFF_yts), by Fun, pretty famously changes to a slower tempo near-instantaneously after the intro. If you're looking for something well-known and poppy, this is probably it, but it sounds more like "a fast part and a slow part" to me than a "real" slowdown, even though it never returns to the faster tempo.

Apparently a lot of trap and other EDM songs slow down heading into the drop, but I couldn't verify any examples.

Answer (score -1):

Layla by Derek & the Dominoes

Comment: Something definetly changes here, but it this does not look like change in tempo - rather some instrumetal complexity goes a little bit down.